# can anyone tell with me why nextflow resume is not working?

Tags: bash, conda, bioinformatics, biopython, nextflow

i have a project with a lot process, I was try so many times -resume but it's not working, I don't know why every time I use -resume, its sill stay and restart at bwa process, I think it wrong in

```
        when:
          check_txt.name == "YES_PASS_workflow2_.txt" || check_txt.name == "Adapter_no_clear_.txt" && check_txt.name !="NO_PASS_.txt"
```

of bwa but when i delete it no case return, i try use cache = 'lenient' but it not working here is my code:

````
process FASTQC_check_final {
  publishDir "${params.outdir}/$name/check", mode:'copy'
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/check", pattern: "*_result.txt"
    tag "FASTQC on ${name}"
  input:
    //fastqc_output
    val(name)
    path(folder_fastqc)
    //fastqc_trimnomatic_out
    val(name1)
    path(folder_trimnomatic)
    //bash file
  output:
    path("*_.txt")
    path("*_result.txt")
  script:
  """
  pwd=\$(pwd)
  cd $projectDir/${params.outdir}/$name
  bash  $projectDir/data/bin/bash.sh ${params.outdir}
  python $projectDir/data/bin/fastqc_check.py ${name}
  mv *.txt \$pwd
  """
}process bwa_map {
  cache = 'lenient'
  publishDir "${params.outdir}/${name}", mode:'copy'
        tag "BWA on $name"
        input:
          //trimnomatic
          val(name)
          path(reads_1)
          path(reads_2)
          //fastqc_check
          path(check_txt)
          path(check_txt_2)
          //raw_reads_for_adapter
          tuple val(sample_name), path(reads)
          //adapter
          path(adapter_dir_)
        // when:
        //   check_txt.name == "YES_PASS_workflow2_.txt" || check_txt.name == "Adapter_no_clear_.txt" && check_txt.name !="NO_PASS_.txt"
          output: 
          tuple val(name), path("${name}.bam")
        // BWA --> sam file, samtoools --> Bam file       //  bwa mem ${params.wholegenehg38_bed} ${reads1} ${reads2} | samtools view -S -b > ${name}.bam 
        script:
        """
          if [ -f "YES_PASS_workflow2_.txt" ]; then
            bwa mem ${params.wholegenehg38_bed} ${reads_1} ${reads_2} | samtools view -S -b > "${name}.bam"
          fi

          if [ -f "Adapter_no_clear_.txt" ]; then
            trimmomatic PE -phred33 ${reads[0]} ${reads[1]} \
              "${reads[0].baseName}_trimmed.fastq" "${sample_name}_unpaired_1.fq" \
              "${reads[1].baseName}_trimmed.fastq" "${sample_name}_unpaired_2.fq" \
              ILLUMINACLIP:${adapter_dir_}:2:30:10 LEADING:5 TRAILING:5 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:30 MINLEN:70 AVGQUAL:25
            bwa mem ${params.wholegenehg38_bed} "${reads[0].baseName}_trimmed.fastq" "${reads[1].baseName}_trimmed.fastq" | samtools view -S -b > "${name}.bam"
          fi
        """
    }
workflow {
read_pairs_ch = Channel .fromFilePairs(params.reads)
//Workflow_1,check and control:
FASTQC(read_pairs_ch)
trimmomatic(read_pairs_ch)
FASTQC_trimnomatic(trimmomatic.out)
FASTQC_check_final(FASTQC.out,FASTQC_trimnomatic.out)

//Workflow_2 if pass
bwa_map(trimmomatic.out,FASTQC_check_final.out,read_pairs_ch,params.adapter_dir)
bamfile_sort(bwa_map.out)
.....
.....
.....
}```


can anyone explain to me why???
````